# SSH running in background (-f) with sshpass

Tags: ssh, bash, ssh-tunnel

My final goal is to use both ssh -f and sshpass together, although it is quite not works.
ssh -f tries to fork from the ssh process and also sets stdin to read from /dev/null - what makes things difficult because sshpass gathers the ssh command, executes it and passes the password to it as input (stdin).
I don't want to use & because basically it's not an elegant way to solve it.
Also, sshpass does not support this incident.

Example for command:
`sshpass -p pass1234 ssh -L 1234:127.0.0.1:5678 -N -f root@1.2.3.4`

If you either remove the '-f' flag or remove the 'sshpass' command you'll see it works great.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this incident?
Thanks.

Comment: You can consider [public key authentication](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/key) and remove the need for a password altogether.

Comment: That's just not an option for anyone who would ask this question.

Comment: @AeroWindwalker why is that? I searched for this question, and I would have asked it if it wasn't already here. I used public key authentication as a solution, which works great.

Answer (score 3):

Do NOT use `sshpass`. It's broken. And not only because of security considerations.

`sshpass` works by creating a pseudo-tty in which it runs `ssh`. The problem with `sshpass` + `ssh -f` is that `ssh -f` first authenticates the user, forks a child to handle the connection and then exits. But `sshpass` will pull the rug from under the child as soon as the parent `ssh` has exited, before the child had any chance to detach itself from the terminal (the pseudo-tty created by `sshpass`) and consequently it will be killed by a `SIGHUP` signal.

A workaround would be to give the child a little time to start:

```
sshpass -p password sh -c 'ssh -f -N ... user@host && sleep .1'
```

BTW, you can *almost* perfectly emulate `sshpass` with `script(1)`:

```
{ sleep .1; echo password; } | script -q /dev/null -c 'ssh user@host cmd'
```

On BSD, you `script` has a different syntax:

```
{ sleep .1; echo password; } | script -q /dev/null ssh user@host cmd
```

Comment: `Do NOT use sshpass` what do you suggest instead?

Comment: sshpass is fine. In all cases where people would use it security is no concern.

Comment: Also you cannot emulate emulate `sshpass` with `script(1)` for example your sshpass example does work but the script example doesn't. @mosvy

Comment: @AeroWindwalker __1.__ sshpass is not fine, as the OP's problem shows, whose causes I have explained in my A __2.__ the script example works (since it's a hack/workaround, you may have to adjust the timeouts, and use the same trick as with sshpass in the command). __3.__ wrt the Bugs section of sshpass manpage: if you're in any way afiliated with sshpass, I suggest you study how xterm and other programs are doing it. Even my screeds ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478969) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538271)) may help. You can easily use a pty master in blocking mode.

Comment: @Jachdich some instrumentation tool like expect/libexpect. It also has interfaces in other languages, not just tcl. For a quick & dirty hack, use script, as in my answer ;-)